# Open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in an android when read file from download file

Tags: android, permissions, readfile

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application ...
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

I make this change but still issue is there it gives me error like ENOENT: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), open '/storage/emulated/0/Download/config.xlsx'

Comment: You do not have rights to access files in `Download/` on Android 11 or higher, unless your app placed the file there originally. Use the Storage Access Framework, such as `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`, and allow the user to choose what file to open. The user will have access to everything in `Download/`.

Comment: So that you mean no solutions to read data directly from file path location.

Comment: There are no solutions for ordinary apps, and my guess is that your app is an ordinary app. If you were writing a file manager, you might have a legitimate need for the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Requesting that permission pretty much guarantees that you will not be allowed to distribute the app on the Play Store (and perhaps elsewhere), unless you have that legitimate need.